# NodeJS http-proxy error response.end() not working

Tags: node.js, http-proxy

Here's the code:

```
 proxy.web(
  req,
  res,
  { changeOrigin: false, target: 'http://' + gotDomain.ip + ':' + gotDomain.port },
  function (error, req, res) => {
    console.log('Error')
    res.end('Error')
  }
)
```

If I stop the target server, the console log fires.

The response `res.end('Error')` does not work.

The request just hangs on the client side. I can run any code I want in the error callback and I can see the `res` variable is an http response object. I've tried adding:

```
 res.writeHead(500, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  });
```

I've tried using the `proxy.on('error'...` setup and the results are exactly the same:

- The callback runs
- The `res` variable is a valid http response object
- Whatever I put in `res.end()` doesn't get sent to the client
- The client hangs forever waiting for a response.

I've checked this answer:

[Node.js http-proxy: Error response not sent to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260825/node-js-http-proxy-error-response-not-sent-to-client)

I'm not sure how that solution could work because my proxy response doesn't have `status()` or `send()` methods. I get `TypeError: res.status is not a function` if I try those.

With http-proxy, I use `end()` whenever I'm returning a response.